# execute maven mainclass multiple times with different sets of arguments

Tags: maven, maven-2

how can i invoke maven mainclass multiple times with different arguments

```
<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <mainClass>TestExecutionInitiator</mainClass>
            <classpathScope>test</classpathScope>
            <arguments>
                <argument>Chrome</argument>
            </arguments>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

So far i could initiate my main class passing argument as 'Chrome'.
I want to invoke the main class with another argument Firefox.
When i run mvn exec:java my main class should invoke multiple times.

Comment: did you try copy paste and make more plugin element  copies?

Comment: I tried to make more plugin, but its executing only the last plugin.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use several executions like the following:

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>exec-1</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals><goal>exec</goal></goals>
            <configuration>
              <mainClass>TestExecutionInitiator</mainClass>
              <classpathScope>test</classpathScope>
              <arguments>
                  <argument>Chrome</argument>
              </arguments>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>exec-2</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals><goal>exec</goal></goals>
            <configuration>
              WhatEver Configuration
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Comment: I tried the above configuration but it throws error as "The parameters 'mainClass' for goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java are missing or invalid"

Comment: so add the main class tag in both executions

Answer (score 0):

Pass the argument as a maven environment variable:

```
<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <mainClass>TestExecutionInitiator</mainClass>
            <classpathScope>test</classpathScope>
            <arguments>
                <argument>${myArg}</argument>
            </arguments>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

and execute it this way:

```
mvn exec:exec -DmyArg=Chrome
```